# Xamarin Android App with online MySql/Sql database

Tags: c#, android, mysql, database, xamarin

I want to know how to connect an android application with an online database.

I read a lot on internet but I'm still in the air. I don't know which methode is the best.

1. I saw something from google like [Sql google cloud](https://cloud.google.com/sql/)
2. I read a lot about Azure.

I saw that all of these services are not entirely free.

I want that my android application from user phone to comunicate with this database, but I don't want to expose sql querys in the codebehind of this app. So I need that this app to send a request somewhere and from there to execute these querys.

Because this is my first Android app, I don't know how to procede in this situation. And I want to use Xamarin.

So the user must insert some data or read some data from database.

Can you give me some examples regarding of my situation?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/web_services/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Xamarin Android App with online MySql/Sql database

You could refer to :

- [Xamarin Android Online Database Tutorial about MySQL database](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FOZ8HNJMXXg)
- [How to connect online DB Xamarin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44173100/how-to-connect-online-db-xamarin)
- [Xamarin.Android connection with MySql databae](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/46459/xamarin-android-connection-with-mysql-databae)

Comment: Thank you [York Shen - MSFT]. There are good information.