# Connecct Database to Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin

I´m working on an Xamarin App, for this App I wanted to use a MS Access database from which I can get the data and display it in the App. Now my question is, how to connect the database to the Xamarin Application and display the data. 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: you want to deploy a local db with the app, or connect to a remote db?  Do you also need to write to the db?

Comment: I want to use an extern database which i want to write myself.

Comment: Access is not really designed for remote or concurrent access.  I would strongly suggest using a "real" SQL database and not Access.  MySQL is free and fairly easy to use if you know how to use Access.

Comment: Thanks for your answers! One last question, are there some tutorials you can recommend me? To learn it better.

Comment: Have a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48383008/xamarin-android-app-with-online-mysql-sql-database) may help.  If you would like to use a local database, you can read [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/data/databases);

Comment: My MySQL database is ready now, but I still have the problem that I don´t really know how to connect the database to my app and display the data. Do you have some ideas for me or some good tutorials?