# WebService for MySQL database

Tags: c#, mysql, web-services, xamarin

I want to create a WebService which communicates with my MySQL database, the data of the database should be displayed on a Xamarin App later on. But at first I got stuck at a point of my WebService and don´t really know how to get further (I´m kinda new to programming and MySQL). Here is a piece of my code (the code is from personPersistance class):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using SimpleRESTServer.Models;
using MySql.Data;


namespace SimpleRESTServer
{
    public class PersonPersistance
    {

        private MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection conn;

        public PersonPersistance()
        {
            string myConnectionString;
            myConnectionString = "server=127.0.0.1;uid=Local Instance MySQL80; pwd=;database=employeedb";
            try
            {
                conn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection();
                conn.ConnectionString = myConnectionString;
                conn.Open();
            }
            catch (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException ex)
            {

            }

        }
        public long savePerson(Person personToSave)
        {
            String sqlString = " INSERT INTO tblpersonnel (FirstName, LastName) VALUES ('"+ personToSave.FirstName + "','" + personToSave.LastName + "')";}
            MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand cmd = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(sqlString, conn);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            long id = cmd.LastInsertedId;
            return id;
        }

    }
}
```

I used this tutorial for my WebService: https://youtu.be/LpySuvYPMZQ

Everthing works as it should till I come to the savePerson function. In my database I insert the ID manually, in the tutorial it gets inserted automatically (I think). So my problem is that I don´t really know how to go on at this point.

Here is a picture of my database columns it may help:

[MySQL database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rL7I5.png)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Before continue, consider using Sql parameters to prevent SQL Injection. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp

Comment: If I don´t want a user Login and just display the data on the app, do I need the sql parameters too?

Comment: Even while displaying data, your app will be in risk. Read the link I provided. Anyway, it's a good practice to use parameterize your query all the time.
Example on displaying data: `"SELECT * FROM [Users] WHERE UserId = " + UserId;`
Imagine inserting this line after providing the Id: `DROP TABLE [Users];` so the Users table will be gone :)

Comment: Ok thanks. After I´ve done that, how should i continue to solve the problem I mentioned above (Sorry I´m kinda new to programming and MySQL so my questions a probably kinda bad).

Comment: It depends on your table, but most of the time, your table will have a unique value for the Id and has Auto increment so you'll not need to provide an Id for your rows, but the database will create that Id and add it to the new inserted Row. Please note, ID column shouldn't be null.

Comment: I notice you add the xamarin tab, oo you want to achieve xamarin android connect to the  online MySql/Sql database, If so, you can refer to this link.https://stackoverflow.com/a/48393410/10627299

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Auto increment while creating your table so you don't need to provide an Id for every row while inserting data.
Based on [MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html)

You create your table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Personnel (
     Id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     Firstname varchar(30),
     Lastname varchar(30),
     PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Now, you can provide the Firstname and Lastname and the database will take care of the Id column.

**Note**, in your table, you allow NULL on Id but that's wrong. You never allow NULL on Id column since it's the identifier and most of operations on the rows will depend on Id column.

As I mentioned in the comments, use **SQL parameters** while inserting data to prevent SQL Injection.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Agree the ID shouldn´t be allowed to be 0, that´s a kinda dumb mistake. However, thank you for your help!

Comment: @SpaceX_Fans If you solve this issue, please mark it this answer, it will help others whoh have similar issue.

Comment: Thanks guys your effort helped me a lot!